# Downloading the whole content of my storage into another computer

Tags: downloads, online-storage

my laptoo was stolen, so I'd like to download the whole content stored in Ubuntu One into another laptop. Is is possible? I can only find the option to download single files.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One is a file synchronization service. If you simply install the client, log in, and subscribe to all your folders in the client, all your files will be downloaded by the client.

There is no way on the web site to download all your files at once though, no.